# How to set a custom value for model field in django RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView class in my api views and on update it doesn't automatically update a data field named as **published**. I want to manually update when the PUT request is sent. How can I do that.
Here is the code

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):

    class PostObjects(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset().filter(status='published')

    options = (
        ('published', 'Published'),
        ('draft', 'Draft')
    )

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    excerpt = models.TextField(null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date=True)
    published = models.DateField(null=True, default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts', default=1)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=options, default='published')
    objects = models.Manager()
    postobjects = PostObjects()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-published',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

view.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from blog.models import Post
from .serializers import PostSerializer


class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.postobjects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer


class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Comment: Can you share your `PostSerializer` class?

Answer (score 0):

On PostDetail, instead of setting the `queryset` attribute, override the `get_object` method to find the specific POST instance you want to update, and then ensure you send the 'published' key: value pair in the payload on submit.

Something like this:

```
class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
  serializer_class = PostSerializer
  
  def get_object(self):
     _id = self.request.data.get('id')
     return get_object_or_404(Post, pk=_id)
```

SAMPLE PUT request:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "title": "New Post Title",
    "published": <required-date-format-for-your-project>
}
```